# Preference Activity Brainstorm

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Is it possible to write a work around to the systems volume functions using a preference activity?

Like say I wanted to output a message to the user if the volume is set too loud it would pop up a toast saying "Hey the volume is too loud"

I know how to make toasts right now I am thinking about the pref activity.
just kicking around ideas here.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class volman extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dhd);

    DialogPreference dp = (DialogPreference) findPreference("mediavolume");
    dp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            SeekBar volumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            final AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            volumeBar.setMax(manager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));
            volumeBar.setProgress(manager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));

            volumeBar
                    .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            Toast.makeText(volman.this, "Lift off.... StartSpark", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            Toast.makeText(volman.this, "Now Stopping", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            manager.setStreamVolume(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, progress,
                                    AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                            Toast.makeText(volman.this, "Now going quiet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private DialogPreference findPreference(String string) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And now for logcat:

```
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] Android Launch!
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] Performing sync
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'ICS'
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] Uploading volman4.0.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-07 15:25:00 - volman4.0] Installing volman4.0.apk...
[2012-07-07 15:25:10 - volman4.0] Success!
[2012-07-07 15:25:11 - volman4.0] /volman4.0/bin/volman4.0.apk installed on device
[2012-07-07 15:25:11 - volman4.0] Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the volume level isn't as straight forward as seems... There are many different streams, when a user leaves your app the volume can change, a user might be connect to speakers with their own volume control, etc.

There is an option to define which stream the volume buttons should affect: [Activity.setVolumeControlStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setVolumeControlStream%28int%29).

But I suggest focusing on the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), it is filled with useful methods and Intents like [AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY).

If you want specific help please post the relevant code that you have written and any logcat errors.  Hope that helps!

Comment: sure give me a moment, I'll post it up in the question field.